# How many session objects are needed for synchronous in-graph replication?

Tags: python, tensorflow

When using synchronous in-graph replication I only call `tf.Session.run()` once.

**Question 1:** Do I still have to create a new session object for each worker and have to pass the URL of the master server (the one that calls `tf.Session.run()`) as the session target?

**Question 2:** Can I get the session target for each server by using `server.target` or do I have to specify the URL of the master server specifically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using "in-graph replication", the graph contains multiple copies of the computational nodes, typically with one copy per device (i.e. one per worker task if you're doing distributed CPU training, or one per GPU if you're doing distributed or local multi-GPU training). Since all of the replicas are in the same graph, you only need one `tf.Session` to control the entire training process. You **don't** need to create `tf.Session` objects in the workers that don't call `Session.run()`.

For in-graph training, it's typical to have a single master that is separate from the worker tasks (for performance isolation), but you could colocate it with your client program. In that case, you could simply create a single-task job called `"client"` and in that task create a session using `server.target`. The following example shows how you could write a single script for your `"client"`, `"worker"`, and `"ps"` jobs:

```
server = tf.train.Server({"client": ["client_host:2222"],
                          "worker": ["worker_host0:2222", ...],
                          "ps": ["ps_host0:2222", ...]})

if job_name == "ps" or job_name == "worker":
    server.join()

elif job_name == "client":
    # Build a replicated graph.
    # ...

    sess = tf.Session(server.target)

    # Insert training loop here.
    # ...
```

Comment: May I also call server.join() for each worker? Or how do I integrate the workers without creating a tf.Session object for each worker?

Comment: Yes, calling `server.join()` will be important (otherwise the worker will have nothing else to do, and it will just exit). I'm not 100% sure what you mean by "integrating" the workers, but the main thing you have to ensure is that all of your processes have a `tf.train.Server` that's created with the same `tf.train.ClusterSpec`, and that cluster spec names all of the workers (and PS tasks).

Comment: On the workers, I get the message "Started server with target: grpc://localhost:1338". The master calls tf.Session.run() and the master process ends once it all done. Unfortunately, the worker does still only show  "Started server with target: grpc://localhost:1338" and does not end its process. Is there a way to automatically end the process of each worker once the master is done?

Comment: There's nothing built-in to support this - typically our users have some kind of cluster management system to support this (and restart the processes in the event of failure). You could potentially use TensorFlow ops such as a queue to signal that the job was completed (e.g. all the workers would issue a blocking dequeue on an empty queue, and the master would enqueue num_workers elements to the queue when it was finished) but that might not be robust to failures etc.

Comment: Is there a write-up on the difference between client and worker somewhere @mrry?